# Is it possible to scan Fingerprint using android mobile screen and application?

Tags: android

Is is feasible to use our android mobile phone screen as figure print scanner, if yes then how to do that?

Comment: "Is is feasible to use our android mobile phone screen as figure print scanner" -- no.

Comment: If fingerprint scanning were possible in the screen, then we would do the same in computer monitors a long time ago

Answer (score 1):

Due to the screen not being as sensitive as a touch receiver, it cannot detect something as fine (in terms of size) as a fingerprint.

There is a reason Samsung and Sony and Apple and many more are using external sensors. Those aren't touch based, they have a different technology that allows them to see the tiny variation in the skin that makes out the fingerprint.

All of the apps who currently claim to scan your fingerprint don't. They detect touch and simulate a fingerprint scan, but it isn't actually scanned.

Answer (score 1):

As current phones touch screens are not as sensitive as fingerprint readers - you cannot do that.

[Here](https://youtu.be/zoR3wyiVzbY?t=2m19s) is a great explanation how modern touchscreens works - it sheds more light on the topic that concerns you.

Answer (score 1):

The screen is not sensitive enough for it to work like a fingerprint scanner. There is a reason there is a separate scanner for fingerprint on for an instance Samsung s5 and s6 and iPhone 5s and 6